# Rotating a scaled sphere with openGL

Tags: opengl, 3d, rotation

I'm attempting to draw an eclipse-shaped object so I used a sphere and scaled it as necessary. I'm attempting to rotate this eclipse-shaped object with the following code but it won't budge (or at least it doesn't look like it's budging). I've tested by simply changing to another 3D shape and it rotates. Is there something I'm doing wrong? What's so different about a `glutSolidSphere`?

```
glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(subx, suby + y, subz);
    glScalef(9.0, 1.75, 1.75);
    glRotatef(angle, 0, 1, 0);
    glTranslatef(-subx, -suby, -subz);
    glTranslatef(subx, suby, subz);
    glutSolidSphere(1.0, 50, 50);
glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: If you move the ``Rotate`` to before the ``Scale`` does that fix the problem?

Comment: @undeadherbs Yes it does!

Comment: The problem was that you were rotating the sphere while it was still spherical, and then stretching it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue as pointed out above in comments was that I was rotating the sphere before I stretched it. Scaling and then rotating fixed the issue.

```
glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(subx, suby + y, subz);
    glRotatef(angle, 0, 1, 0);
    glScalef(9.0, 1.75, 1.75);
    glTranslatef(-subx, -suby, -subz);
    glTranslatef(subx, suby, subz);
    glutSolidSphere(1.0, 50, 50);
glPopMatrix();
```